# SharePoint online Suite bar and List command bar loading issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

Most of the time Suite bar and command bar in a list (new experience) on SharePoint online doesn't load. However this issue is intermittent, but any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue on my windows 10 machine. Your site needs to be in the Local Intranet section of Security settings in IE. We had ours in Trusted sites and it would not work on my machine until we moved.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. I've tried in both Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

Suite bar and Command bar in new experience for List started working properly after adding an item (first item) into the list. **Suite bar and command bar Loading issue persist for a list with no items.**

Steps performed:

1. Changed the experience to Classic experience in the Advance settings for List
2. Added a first item (new item) into the list using classic New item form
3. Changed the experience back to New experience in the List Advance settings
4. Boom - suite bar and command bar is loading properly!